# Which version of the jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped nuget package should I use with jquery v2.1.4

Tags: jquery, typescript, definitelytyped

I assume the latest version of the nuget package (currently 2.8.3) supports the recently released, jquery v2.2.0.  But, my project is still using jquery v2.1.4.  Which jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped nuget package should I use with jquery v2.1.4?

Comment: There was a discussion on this... but AFAIK it never really got implemented (when you times the number of library versions by the number of TypeScript language versions, you realise the task is monumental). https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped version 2.3.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/2.3.3). I chose it simply because it is the most downloaded version of the package.  I have not had any issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't have much of a choice because there is only this file in the end:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts

and no versions are assigned to it. You can see a comment in the header:

```
// Type definitions for jQuery 1.10.x / 2.0.x
```

Moreover, [release announcement](http://blog.jquery.com/2016/01/08/jquery-2-2-and-1-12-released/) for jQuery 2.2.0 claims there are no breaking changes, so it should be safe for you to use `jquery.d.ts` file.

Comment: But, I would prefer to get the file from [nuget package on nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/).   But, there appears to be several produced each day.  But, as far as I can tell, there is no way to know which version of jquery they correspond to.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Well, it's not ideal situation. However, jquery versions are not typically that different, so you should be ok with either version.

Comment: This is crazy. jQuery is at 3.1.x and still no Typescript definitions. It's only THE most popular JS library. Is Typescript dead/doomed?

Comment: @marchy: Quick google: There is a nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/3.1.2 that is based on commit: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/2c65d5ca7267fda6d49a3b447c8b089632fb5358/jquery/jquery.d.ts ... I guess you'll be fine with latest definition file. jQuery does not change that much (I know that it is not a consolation but anyway..)

Comment: @MartinVseticka oh thanks so much Martin. That's fantastic to hear it. TypeScript back on the table 